# CSS Dropdown Selection

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a CSS dropdown that gives me a list of options. 
Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><span class="thisChoice">-choose wisely-</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Choice One</li>
            <li>Choice Two</li>
            <li>Choice Three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
ul ul{
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}
```

When you click on an option, the JavaScript changes the text in the  tag to the text of the option you've chosen. 
My question is, is there a way to get the dropdown to collapse again once you've clicked on your choice?
1. I've tried using jQuery to change the CSS for the embedded *ul*, but it breaks the functionality altogether.
2. I've tried to use *document.getElementById("anythingElse").focus()* to try to make the CSS think the mouse moved away from the dropdown.
The best solution, or at least the one I'm hoping for, is one that will make the browser think the mouse has moved off of the dropdown just long enough for the embedded *ul* to hide.

Comment: Why dont you use `<select>` & `<option>` and modify that with css..

Comment: The wheel has already been invented: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#buttonDropdowns

Comment: Can you create a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) containing all the relevant CSS, HTML, and JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul li:hover > ul:active {
    display:none;
}
```

I'm not sure if your js will be able to load though.

example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/MFb3v/